# HDIV Integration with RESTful webservice

Tags: hdiv

I'm creating a web application containing RESTful webservices and I was wondering how I can properly integrate HDIV with this part of my webapp.

For now, I'm defining each webservice URL as startPage:

```
<hdiv:startPages>/ws/ws1,/ws/ws2,...</hdiv:startPages>
```

Is there a way to change that? does `<hdiv:startPages>/ws/*</hdiv:startPages>` or something like that exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java patterns to define start pages:

```
<hdiv:startPages>/ws/.*</hdiv:startPages>
```

Anyway, you can try [Spring HATEOAS](http://projects.spring.io/spring-hateoas/) and [Hdiv's experimental](https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/tree/hdiv-hateoas) integration to securize the REST services.

Comment: I will look at these links. Thank you for your answer.